# Movement Buttons that respond to touch

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

So I have been working at writing this code for weeks (I am a beginner at AS3), but cannot for the life of me figure out how write working movement buttons that receive touch input. This code is modeled after one of the Adobe Samples, but when I run it just doesnt work.

Here is my code:

```
package MovementButtons
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.TouchEvent;


    public class TouchInput extends MovieClip
    {
        public var bLeftPressed:Boolean = true;
        public var bRightPressed:Boolean = true;

        public var nSpeed:Number = 100;
    }

    public function TouchInput()
    {
        left_btn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, TouchBeginHandler, false, 0, true);
        left_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.TOUCH_END, TouchEndHandler, false, 0, true);
        right_btn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, TouchBeginHandler, false, 0, true);
        right_btn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, TouchEndHandler, false, 0, true);

        //Updating Screen
        addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, enterFrameMoveHandler);
    }

    protected function enterFrameMoveHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
    {
        var click.txt:String= "The function is working";
        while ( bLeftPressed ) {
            guy_mc.x -= nSpeed;
        }
        while( bRightPressed ) {
            guy_mc.x += nSpeed;
        }
    }

    protected function TouchBeginHandler(event:TouchEvent):void
    {
        click.txt = "Its clicked.";
        switch ( event.target )
        {
            case left_btn:
                left = true;
                break;
            case right_btn:
                right = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    protected function TouchEndHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        switch ( event.target )
        {
            case left_btn:
                left = false;
                break;
            case right_btn:
                right = false;
                break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`Multitouch.inputMode`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#inputMode). That determines what type of touch input the app accepts. It defaults to `GESTURE` when you need it to be `TOUCH_POINT`.

Alternatively, you can just use `MouseEvent` equivalents instead. On a touch device, `MouseEvent`s are dispatched in pretty much the same way that `TouchEvent`s are. Most devs ignore the `TouchEvent` class altogether unless there is a specific reason they need to use it.

For future reference, you should include more details in a question other than "it doesn't work". We're trying to debug a problem blindly here so the more information you can give us, the better. Luckily, this is a fairly common problem when dealing with touch events

Comment: Alright, thanks so much for the help. Ill try to give more information next time haha.

Comment: If this correctly answers your question, please mark it as correct (the checkbox under the number next to the question) to close it.

Comment: Okay, I changed the TouchEvents to MouseEvent, and my code still does nothing :\. I simply want a block to move while you are holding the mouse, and I think the issue may be with the enterFrameMoveHandler function. I changed it to recieve on Event.ENTER_FRAME, but I think the problem is that I only have one frame. Any suggestions?